# libluajit-5.1.so.2:cann't open shared object file:No such file or directory

Tags: gcc, lua

I want to test luajit's c api on my hosts,following is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <luajit.h>
#include <lualib.h>
#include <lauxlib.h>

int main()
{
    lua_State *L;
    L=luaL_newstate();
    luaL_openlibs(L);
    lua_pushnumber(L,10);
    lua_pushstring(L,"hello");
    lua_pushboolean(L,0);
    lua_close(L);
    //printf("luatop:%d\n",lua_gettop(L));
    return 0;
}
```

Then I compile it with gcc:

```
gcc -I /usr/local/include/luajit-2.0/ -lluajit-5.1 test_lua.c -o test_lua
```

But when I run it

```
$ ./test_lua
```

it prompts that,

```
./test_lua: error while loading shared libraries: libluajit-5.1.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Somebody know how to solve it?

Comment: Running `strace -e open ./test_lua` should tell you the actual path of the shared library it's trying to load. Then look what's wrong with it (the error message claims it isn't there). It could be that you need to install some development package or set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` ...

Comment: `strace` is Linux only, btw. For BSDs there is `ktrace`/`kdump`, OSX has `dtruss`, etc.

Answer (score 4):

set up LD_LIBRARY_PATH variable， make it reference to libluajit-5.1.so.2 live directory.

cmd：

**export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH**